# Is there a plural 's' on "phase" in "... apply to both the first and the second phase[s] of the ..."?

Tags: grammatical-number

I'm currently writing this in a document:

> Attributes of a clean build:
>
> - it has no warnings
> - it uses the highest warning level
> - it treats warnings as errors
>
> They apply to both the compilation and the linking phases of the build.

However, "phases" doesn't sit quite right with me... should it be singular?

Comment: You wouldn't say *They apply to both phase* . . . so, no.

Answer (score 1):

You could either treat them as a single phase:

> They apply to the compilation/linking phase of the build.

This is reasonable since the distinction between compilation and linking is irrelevant in this context.

Or you can repeat "phase":

> They apply to both the compilation phase and the linking phase of the build.